# Dates in Grails 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: date, grails

I just upgraded a Grails application from 2.2 to 2.3 and ran into some errors in my code regarding dates. As soon as I upgraded, my dates were failing validation. The dates are in the format "MM/DD/yyyy HH:mm" . Grails 2.2 were handling them fine, but 2.3 cannot bind to a Date object. I've done a work around by parsing the text into a date object, but it's not as clean as I would like.

Comment: you must have tried the date parse function with simple date format ? even in 2.2 ? you need it right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the date format to `grails.databinding.dateFormats` in `Config.groovy`.

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = ['MM/DD/yyyy HH:mm']
```

[The data binding documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) goes into more detail.

Answer (score 1):

The databinding was changed significantly in 2.3, and this is almost certainly the cause of your problem. If you want to use the old databinding behaviour in Grails 2.3 add the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder = true
```

Comment: Even though this may fix the problem, This is not recommended, spring databinder is deprecated in favor of new enhanced grails data binding mechanism, and this setting should not be enabled.